# How do you filter for a string (not) containing a substring in an Azure Data Factory data flow expression?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

As someone with a background in Alteryx, it has been a slow process to get up to speed with the expressions and syntax within Azure Data Factory data flows. I am trying to filter out rows containing the following string in a similar manner to this Alteryx filter code below:

```
!Contains([Subtype], "News")
```

After scrolling through all the string expressions in Azure Data Factory, I am struggling to find anything similar to the logic above. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide me on this front!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ****Filter** transformation** in ADF Data flow and give the condition
for any column like below:

**My Sample Data:**

[image]


Here I am filtering out the rows the which contains a string of `"Rakesh"` in the `Name` column with the Data flow expression `instr(Name,"Rakesh")==0`.
**instr()** returns number of common letters. Our condition satisfies if its result is 0.

**Filter Transformation:**
.
[image]

**Output in Data preview of filter:**

You can see the remaining rows only in the result.

[image]

Comment: Additionally, if you are looking for an expression function that finds strings inside of strings, you can use like() and instr().

Comment: yeah, we can use like that as well.